# In one of my environment , NICs should have only one ipconfig

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

So I wrote a powershell to remove rest of the ipconfigurations from NIC . $sidname variable value will be given in pipeline like "S1:S2:S3" . So Ipconfiguration names under NIC will be like "ipconfig-S1, ipconfig-S2, ipconfig-S3" . Under Nic1 I need to delete ipconfig-S2, ipconfig-S3. below script is not showing any error but its not deleting what I wanted to delete. Am I doing anything wrong here?

```
for($i=1; $i le 2; $i++)
{$nic1 = Get=AzNetworkInterface -Name nic-0($i) -ResourceGroupName "rg--"
$sidArray =$sidname.Split(":")
Remove-AzNetworkInterfaceIpConfig -Name ipconfig-$sidArray[1] -NetworkInterface $nic1 |Set-AzNetworkInterface
Remove-AzNetworkInterfaceIpConfig -Name ipconfig-$sidArray[2] -NetworkInterface $nic1 |Set-AzNetworkInterface
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors in your script. I have corrected them for you. Please refer to my script:

```
$sidname = "S1:S2:S3"
for($i=1; $i -le 2; $i++)
{
$nic1 = Get-AzNetworkInterface -Name "nic-0$i" -ResourceGroupName "rg--"
$sidArray =$sidname.Split(":")
$sidArray1 = $sidArray[1]
$sidArray2 = $sidArray[2]
Remove-AzNetworkInterfaceIpConfig -Name "ipconfig-$sidArray1" -NetworkInterface $nic1 | Set-AzNetworkInterface
Remove-AzNetworkInterfaceIpConfig -Name "ipconfig-$sidArray2" -NetworkInterface $nic1 | Set-AzNetworkInterface
}
```

Comment: Now Backend address pools getting double ipcondifurations  i.e primary and secondary from NICs.How can I resolve that